# Require not defined when importing react instead of using cdn

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

The problem happens when I stop using cdn and include react and use import instead.
when I type:

> node index.js

This first code works fine:

**index.html:**

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello React!</title>
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js'></script>
        <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='root'></div>

        <script src='App.js' type='text/babel'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.js:**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <h1>hey</h1>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.static('static'));
app.listen(port);
```

However, when I make these modifications:

Comment the links to react in **index.html**

```
<!--
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js'></script>
-->
```

download react and react-dom with npm

> npm i -S react react-dom

add imports in **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```

I get an error: require not defined

So I want to know why this is happening, and how can I fix it.

Please note that I didn't touch the link to babel

Comment: How are you transpiling with babel in App.js? do you have a .babelrc file?

Comment: yes {"presets":["@babel/preset-react"]}

Comment: Not related to your problem, you don't need to use ```-S``` anymore with ```npm install```. [npm install saves any specified packages into dependencies by default.](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)